# Realtek RTL8821 Ethernet card not detected by Kali Linux

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, kali-linux, dkms

When installing Kali Linux, an error message appears during the "Detect network hardware" step.
The message says: "No Ethernet card was detected. if you know the name of the driver needed by your Ethernet card, you can select it from the list."

I tried all the pilots on the list one by one, but nothing happens. After skipping this step and continuing the installation, I tried to manually install a driver.

My Wi-Fi card is a "Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter."

I found this pilot: "https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce" by reading one of the topics on the same site, but the Wi-Fi does not work even after installation.

When I execute the command:

```
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

I get:

```
About to run dkms install steps...
Error! DKMS tree already contains: rtl8821ce-v5.2.5_1.26055.20180108.1
You cannot add the same module/version combo more than once.

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
'make' -j4 KVER=4.19.0-kali3-amd64.......(bad exit status: 2)
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.19.0-kali3-amd64 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.2.5_1.26055.20180108.1/build/make.log for more information.

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
'make' -j4 KVER=4.19.0-kali3-amd64.....(bad exit status: 2)
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.19.0-kali3-amd64 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.2.5_1.26055.20180108.1/build/make.log for more information.

Finished running dkms install steps.
```

I do not know if the driver is installed correctly or if it is even compatible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Comment: @RalfFriedl no it is not a duplicated subject of Why is Kali ... 
I want to know why the wifi does not work even after installing the driver .

Comment: is it wifi (as per comment) or ethernet (as per question's title)? Most wifi cards need a firmware. This is in addition to a driver

Comment: @A.B Ah ok, I thought the firmware was included with kali. Where can I find it ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Kali tells you NOT to use it if you don't know Linux

Answer (score 0):

[Ndiswrapper](https://wiki.debian.org/NdisWrapper) is a solution, since the [manufacturer](http://realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/rtl8821ae-software) only supports Windows. However, the drivers may be found at https://packages.debian.org/buster/firmware-realtek.